# How to pass array of data to controller?

Tags: ajax, laravel, get, laravel-blade

I'm new here :). I have a problem with my code. I'm working with laravel 5.1 and Blade. In my view I have:

```
function getNumber(){
      values = [];
      values[0] = $('#receipt_type_id').val();
      values[1] = $('#provider_id').val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "{{{ url('receipts/showByNumber') }}}",            
          type: "get",              
          data: {ids: values},              
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
              //i do something
          }                  
      });
  }
```

In my route:

```
Route::get('receipts/showByNumber', ['as' => 'receipt.showByNumber', 'uses' => 'ReceiptsController@showByNumber']);
```

And in my controller:

```
public function showByNumber($values){        
    $receipt_type_id = $values[0];
    $provider_id = $values[1];
    //Find the receipt to edit
    ...
    ...            
}
```

The error is `GET http://manchego.app/receipts/showByNumber?ids%5B%5D=1&ids%5B%5D=2 500 (Internal Server Error)`. I read another topics with the same problem that I have but I can't understand where is my problem.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The `url` attribute on your ajax request looks wrong. Replace the tripple curly brackets with double curly brackets. `url: {{ url('receipts/showByNumber') }},  `. You can use your browsers developer tools to inspect the HTTP requests made by your app. Use it to debug your AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could type-hint the `Request` class (recommended):

```
public function showByNumber(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $allParams = $request->all(); // returns an array
    $provider_id = $request->get('provider_id');
}
```

Or you could use the `Request` facade:

```
public function showByNumber()
{
    $allParams = \Request::all(); // returns an array
    $provider_id = \Request::get('provider_id');
}
```